# C++ error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++

First of all, i need to say, that i am a complete noob.
I am trying to make some naval combat simulation to do that i created a random letter and number generator
Here's the code.
By the way, what i want to achieve is to have only one variable (Guess) to be confronted with the ship places that the user specified.

```
char letters[]= {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L'};

\\ lots of code

//RandomAI
int G = rand() % 10 + 1;
int nOut = rand() % 10 + 1;
char lOut = letters[G];
string Guess = lOut + nOut;
return 0;
```

Comment: `nOut` is an integer.  So it isn't clear what you're expected output should be.  Should it be something like `B3`, `E7`, etc.?  Or do you add 7 to the letter (literally), ex. `'A' + 7` equal to `'H'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string Guess = lOut + nOut;` adds an `int` and `char` types which does not produce a `std::string`. One way to address this is to create a string and then append to it:

```
std::string guess =  lOut + std::to_string(nOut);
```

This will solve your compiler error, but you still have a logic error here:

```
int G = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

`rand() % 10 + 1` will produce a value between 1 and 10 inclusive. You want a number between 0 and 9 inclusive, because indices in C++ begin at 0, not 1. So drop the `+1` portion:

```
int G = rand() % 10;
```

Otherwise you may accidentally attempt to access an out-of-bounds index in `letters`

Comment: `nOut` is an integer, so not really sure what the OP expected.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yeah, I made the assumption he intended to index into `letters` again. I think that's wrong, though. Probably they wanted something like `B3`. I'll update my post.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I'm going to assume "naval combat simulation" means "Battleship".

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue, though i needed a good 5 minutes to figure out that i needed to add the support for c++ 11

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted an output string like 'A7' or 'F2', one way to achieved this would be to convert everything to `string` (since you can't add and `int` and a `char`). For those who don't have access to C++11 and `std::to_string()` yet, you could use:

```
char letters[]= {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L'};
int G = std::rand() % 10;
int nOut = std::rand() % 10;
char lOut = letters[G];
std::stringstream ss;
ss << nOut;
std::string Guess = lOut + ss.str();
```